# How do I disable any kind of function from the f-keys?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, high-sierra, settings

As the question implies, I need some help about the f-keys, more specifically with the f9 key. I have a program that runs in terminal, and I need the f9 key to be completely function-less in order to work properly with it.
**Even with the f-keys standard function option enabled, if I press f9, happens the same thing that would happen by pressing f3 without the standard functions option enabled**. A similar behavioris shared also with f12, that when pressed, gets me instantly to the dashboard. Just do you know, my Mac runs high Sierra. Notice that **I did try to press fn+f9 but that just doesn't work**. Also, if anything's unclear, I will try to explain myself a little better.

Comment: Question: the row of the F keys all have dual function. Which one do you want disabled. In case of F9 it is also fast forward key

Comment: So, to bottom line it, you need `F9` to be disabled completely?  What do you mean by “the standard function”?

Comment: What model of Mac is this? Is the keyboard built-in, or an Apple external, or a third-party one?

Comment: @Allan, The link you attached to your comment is very useful, and I'll see what happens following the instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you all for your help. @Allan's comment was helpful and Based on his answer I researched on the web about key remapping etc. when I found (as you can see in the image attached) that the f9 key was assigned to a shortcut intercepted by the finder. By un-checking the option related to f9 I solved the issue.

[image: Settings>keyboard>shortcuts>mission control]